# How to activate and use CMIS for a SharePoint 2013 Server?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, cmis

I want to sync my SharePoint files to my desktop using [CmisSync](http://cmissync.com/).
To do this, I need to activate the [CMIS protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_Management_Interoperability_Services) on SharePoint.

So, how to access documents stored inside SharePoint Server 2013 from outside, via CMIS?

Comment: thank you for this article.
I installed CMIS on my SP server .. and now i'm trying to test it in a winform app. I added a reference to the service, but honestly i can't find a way to use the methods within this service. ( i want to display the data in a list i have in a sharepoint site (for xpl) in a listbox control.)! Thank you Fadwa

Comment: @user15425 CMIS is not supported for SP List, check the details at **[Configure CMIS In SharePoint 2016](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/sharepoint-2016-configure-cmis)**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Step 1: Make SharePoint accessible from outside (if not already)

On the server, start a powershell window and type the following commands:

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.Sharepoint.Powershell
Get-SPWebApplication -IncludeCentralAdministration
```

Take note of the URL at the `SharePoint Central Administ...` line, then open it in a web browser.

An administration web interface appears. Click on `Application Management` then `Alternate Access Mappings` then `Edit Public URLs`.

In `Alternate Access Mapping Collection` select the site you want to access, probably something like `SharePoint - 80`. In `Public URLs` set `Default` to the URL you must use to access the server, which is probably `http://` or `https://` plus the server name you would use to ping the server from a client machine.

## Step 2: Enable Basic Authentication (if needed)

*(If you want to access via NTLM/SSO, skip this step)*

Return to the main page of the SharePoint Central Administration tool. Click on `Security`, then in the `General Security` section click on `Specify authentication providers`, then on `Default`.

In this page, set `Basic Authentication` to checked.
*Note: To stay secure, make sure you use HTTPS.*

## Step 3: Activate CMIS for your site

Log into the web interface of your site, click the gear icon in the upper-right, click on `Site settings`, then in the `Site Actions` section click on `Manage site features`. In the list that appears, activate the `Content Management Interoperability Services (CMIS) Producer` item:

[image]

## Step 4: Use CMIS

In your CMIS client (for instance [CMIS Workbench](http://chemistry.apache.org/java/developing/tools/dev-tools-workbench.html)), use the following URL:

```
http://yourserver/_vti_bin/cmis/rest?getRepositories
```

(or `http://yourserver/_vti_bin/cmissoapwsdl.aspx` if using Web Services)

and your SharePoint username/password.