# CMIS AtomPub URL: Error 404 at /cmis/rest/ despite CMIS enabled

Tags: cmis

On Windows Server 2012/SharePoint Server 2013 I activated CMIS [like this](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/59190/14701), but when trying to connect to CMIS at `http://myserver/cmis/rest/` I get a 404 error:

```
$ curl -v -u Administrator:mypassword "http://192.168.0.20/cmis/rest/"
> GET /cmis/rest/ HTTP/1.1
> Authorization: Basic QWRtaW5pc3RyYXRvcjpmdWppSTEz
> User-Agent: curl/7.27.0
> Host: 192.168.0.20
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 404 NOT FOUND
< Cache-Control: private,max-age=0
< Content-Length: 13
< Expires: Wed, 30 Jan 2013 06:27:54 GMT
< Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
< X-SharePointHealthScore: 0
< Public-Extension: http://schemas.microsoft.com/repl-2
< SPRequestGuid: 0299fe9b-5958-9008-0000-06e305c41df6
< request-id: 0299fe9b-5958-9008-0000-06e305c41df6
< X-FRAME-OPTIONS: SAMEORIGIN
< SPRequestDuration: 36
< SPIisLatency: 0
< X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
< MicrosoftSharePointTeamServices: 15.0.0.4420
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< X-MS-InvokeApp: 1; RequireReadOnly
< Date: Thu, 14 Feb 2013 06:27:54 GMT
< 
404 NOT FOUND
```

Is it a sign that my SharePoint is not ready to be used as a CMIS server?
It is a collaboration site. I just have a test file uploaded to it. Do I need to create workspaces or anything for CMIS to start working?
I am running CMIS Workbench directly on the server, so I guess it is not a network problem.

Via [CMIS Workbench](http://chemistry.apache.org/java/developing/tools/dev-tools-workbench.html) I get:

```
ient.bindings.spi.atompub.CmisAtomPubSpi: Initializing AtomPub SPI...
ncmis.client.bindings.spi.http.HttpUtils: GET http://myserver/cmis/rest/
ncmis.client.bindings.spi.http.HttpUtils: GET http://myserver/cmis/rest/ > Headers: {null=[HTTP/1.1 404 NOT FOUND], X-SharePointHealthScore=[0], MicrosoftSharePointTeamServices=[15.0.0.4420], Content-Length=[13], Expires=[Thu, 24 Jan 2013 09:37:03 GMT], request-id=[72b5fc9b-e969-9008-0000-0a77440e3439], Server=[Microsoft-IIS/8.0], X-Powered-By=[ASP.NET], Cache-Control=[private,max-age=0], X-Content-Type-Options=[nosniff], SPRequestGuid=[72b5fc9b-e969-9008-0000-0a77440e3439], SPIisLatency=[1], Date=[Fri, 08 Feb 2013 09:37:03 GMT], Public-Extension=[http://schemas.microsoft.com/repl-2], X-FRAME-OPTIONS=[SAMEORIGIN], X-MS-InvokeApp=[1; RequireReadOnly], SPRequestDuration=[30]}
hemistry.opencmis.workbench.ClientHelper: CmisObjectNotFoundException: NOT FOUND
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using the wrong URL, it seems.

It works with `http://myserver/_vti_bin/cmis/rest?getRepositories`

Or for a particular site `site1`: `http://myserver/site1/_vti_bin/cmis/rest?getRepositories`